# Android: find unused string resources taking into account generated binding classes

Tags: android, android-databinding, android-lint

I cannot believe after searching for hours I have not found a reliable solution that will report all truly unused string resources in my android project.

Android Lint does not work because it ignores references to string resources from code in layout XML files that gets included in the generated Binding classes by the Android databinding processor.

Since Android lint is behind the Android Studio Analyze => Run Inspection By Name =>  Unused Resources feature it finds huge number of false positives rendering it useless. I have filed [this bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73249560) on Android Studio on this issue.

Has anyone found a solution that is a reliable and efficient way to find all unused string resources that take into account references in generated binding classes?